# breezejs: orderBy not kept when merging collection to an existing Entity in cache

Tags: breeze

In the cache, I've got an Entity of type 'Mandate'.

Then I run the following code to fetch a collection of MandateHistory entities, which is then merged by breeze to the corresponding property of the Mandate entity :

```
 function getMandatHistory(mandatId) {
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("MandatesHistory")
                .where("Mandate.Id", "==", mandatId).orderBy("Id")
                .expand("Mandate").skip(offset).take(pageSize).inlineCount(true);

            return manager.executeQuery(query.using(service));
 }
```

Note the orderBy clause is respected and the results are properly sorted by Id.

However the items in the collection property of the Mandate entity is NOT sorted. Do I have to do something special here  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting of the values returnd by collection navigation properties is NOT something that Breeze does. It will sort the results of a query, but if you want to sort, ( *and keep sorted*), one of the collection properties of an entity you will need to manage that yourself.

I think your best two options are either.

1) Sort before display.  i.e. call a sort method on any collection right before you display it.  Depending on what MVVM framework you are using, there is often a 'binding' that does exactly this.

2) Subscribe to the Breeze arrayChanged event on the array returned by your navigation property and call sort on the array anytime you see the change event.  Note this can get expensive if you subscribe to a lot properties on a lot of entities.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not too sure how breeze works internally, but I would have thought that the data returned by the executeQuery() method would just be affected to the collection property of my Entity, in which case the sort should stay the same as what is returned by the server. The fact that the collection is not ordered the same way as the returned data, shows that somehow breeze re-orders the items, I don't do that for sure. Maybe I did not understand your reply, but it seems you didn't explained why the collection is re-ordered ?

Comment: Collection properties in Breeze are never ordered, they are filled, (pushed onto existing arrays), as the data is returned from the server and if the same entity is returned more than once by different queries, it is simply merged into the existing instance, so again no reordering will occur.  You might get lucky with this behavior but it would be a bad idea to count on it.  Moreover, if your sort key changes value on either the server or the client, you will still need to account for it.

Comment: Hi @JayTraband, how do I subscribe to `arrayChanged` for all entities of a type? For example, if I have a `Book` entity with a `orders` navigational property, how do I make it such that anytime changes are made to the `orders` property, I get an event notification and I can sort the array?

Comment: book.orders.arrayChanged.subscribe(
function (arrayChangedArgs) {
    var addedEntities = arrayChangedArgs.added;
    var removedEntities = arrayChanged.removed;
});